# Ziggeo error setPreviewTexture failed using Fragment

Tags: android, camera, ziggeo-sdk

I using Fragment set cameraView

There is an error this onResume

```html
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (isCameraAccessGranted() && isRecordAudioGranted() && isWriteStorageGranted()) {
            cvCamera.start();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), VIDEO_PERMISSIONS, 0);
        }
    }
```

I doing Stepper 5 Page Fragment this is PagerAdapter

```html
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, int behavior) {
        super(supportFragmentManager, behavior);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 6;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new BlankFragmentTestCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + position;
    }

}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewPager by default keeps previous and next fragment in the resumed state. So it's like one camera opened on three screens at the same time.
Please, try to

1. Use only 1 fragment with camera view
2. Use flag `FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` for the ViewPager

I've prepared a small working demo, please, take a look
https://github.com/3akat/Ziggeo_CameraView_PagerDemo